# F# Function with variable types

Tags: generics, f#, functional-programming

I have a question on making a function generic so that I can reuse the behavior. I have a situation where I want to perform the same set of actions whether the data is a `float` or a `string`. I have included a bit of the data model so you can see what I am doing. Near the bottom I have two different functions in the `DataSeries` module, `simpleHigh` and `preferredHigh`. The `simpleHigh` function does exactly what I want. You can see that in both cases, `float` or `string`, I am using the same set of functions.

Ideally I could do what I attempt to do in the `preferredHigh` function. I define a single function and then use it for both conditions. The compiler complains though saying there is a type mismatch. I tried making the inner `high` function take a type argument:

```
let high<'T> v = (Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Value) >> Seq.last >> (fun x -> x.Value))
```

But because it is contained inside another function definition the compiler says, "Explicit type parameters may only be used on module or member bindings".

Am I fighting a loosing battle here? Should I just settle with the simple version? My instinct tells me I am missing simple subtle and simple here. I would rather reuse the behavior if possible instead of writing the exact some thing twice. Should I take a different approach? All feedback welcome!

```
open System

type Observation<'T> = {
    ObsDateTime : DateTimeOffset
    Value : 'T
}

type Result =
    | Float of float
    | String of string

type DataSeries =
    | Float of Observation<float> seq
    | String of Observation<string> seq

module DataSeries = 
    let summarise
        (f: float Observation seq -> float)
        (s: string Observation seq -> string)
        (ds: DataSeries) =
        match ds with
        | DataSeries.Float v -> f v |> Result.Float
        | DataSeries.String v -> s v |> Result.String

    // What works
    let simpleHigh ds =
        summarise
            (Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Value) >> Seq.last >> (fun x -> x.Value))
            (Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Value) >> Seq.last >> (fun x -> x.Value))
            ds

    // What I would rather write
    let preferredHigh ds =
        let high v = (Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Value) >> Seq.last >> (fun x -> x.Value))
        summarise
            high
            high
            ds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have `preferredHigh` written right now, it doesn't compile for an entirely different reason: `high` is a function of two arguments (one explicitly defined `v` and another coming from the function composition), but you're passing it to `summarise`, which expects a function of one argument.

So, the obvious way would be to remove the extra argument `v`:

```
let high = (Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Value) >> Seq.last >> (fun x -> x.Value))
```

However, this wouldn't compile for the reason that you have already noted: the compiler determines the type of `high` based on the first usage as `float Observation seq -> float`, and then refuses to accept it in the second usage, because it doesn't match `string Observation seq -> string`.

This (as you probably already know) is due to the fact that in F# values cannot be generic, unless you write them as such explicitly. Aka ["value restriction"](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction).

However, functions *can* be generic. Even nested functions can: even though you can't write the generic parameters explicitly, the compiler would still infer a generic type for a nested function where appropriate.

From this, the solution is obvious: make `high` a function, not a value. Give it an argument, and don't forget to apply the composed function to that argument, so that the resulting function doesn't end up with two arguments (aka ["eta-abstraction"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion)):

```
let high x = (Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Value) >> Seq.last >> (fun x -> x.Value)) x
```

Comment: Oh wow, such a simple thing. Thank you! I don't know why I didn't see that `high` was not a function. Well, I feel silly :) Thanks!